# Friendly URL in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `PointPage` model with `url` field in it. I need to format links to `point_page#show` on website to:

```
domain.com/:url
```

So, I've add to `routes.rb`

```
get ':url', to: 'point_pages#show'
```

And to `point_page.rb`

```
def to_param
  url
end
```

`show` method in `point_page_controller.rb` is:

```
def show
  @point_page = PointPage.find_by(url: params[:url])
end
```

So, everything works, and `domain.com/:url` == `domain.com/point_pages/:url`

But `link_to` method in views generate urls of second type, not the first one:

```
link_to 'Link', point_page_path(page) #=> <a href="/point_pages/url">Link</a>
```

And I need `<a href="/url">Link</a>`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `as` option to the route definition:

```
get ':url', to: 'point_pages#show', as: 'url'
```

This will create an `url_path` route helper:

```
link_to 'Link', url_path(page)
```